# how can get the array size if using vector<float*>

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to store the 2 dimensional array using `vector<float*>`.  `float*` will be assigned by `fread` function. But it can't be got the `float` size inside a,unless using `vector<vector<float>>`.  I don't want to use `vector<vector<float>>` because it needs to convert from array to `vector`.  So any other better methods?

Comment: ".I don't want to use vector< vector< float > > because it needs to convert from array to vector." - can you explain more about the last part?

Answer (score 3):

Use `vector<vector<float>>`. One requirement of vector is that the elements are stored continguously. Said more formally (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular
>   pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a
>   vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an
>   element of an array.

That means you can do something like this:

```
vector<float> x{1.0, 2.0};
float *x1 = &x[0];
```

Comment: My crystal ball is telling me that the OP wants to do `std::fread(x.data(), sizeof(float), n, fp)` which is fine, provided `x.size() >= n`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use `vector<vector<float>>`, one option is to create your own data type.

```
struct MyArray
{
   std::vector<float*> array;
   size_t cols;
};
```

This assumes that `MyArray` does not take responsibility for allocating and deallocating memory of the `float*`s.

`array.size()` is equal to the number of rows and each element of `array` is assumed to hold `cols` number of `float`s.

Comment: Why re-invent vector, in a somewhat crippled form?